# Can we convert a base class pointer to a derived class pointer without knowing its real type?

Tags: c++

If I have a base class `A` with 2 derived class `B` and `C`, is there a simple way to convert a pointer `A*` to `B*` or `C*` without knowing its real type? Without making a switch on the typeid.

Comment: `dynamic_cast` is the only safe way without knowing the type ahead of time. To avoid `dynamic_cast`ing, I'll sometimes use `enum`s to store its type.

Comment: Short answer: No.  Normally you should use polymorphism so you don't need to know the type.

Comment: you can use dyanmic_cast and check a base pointer actually contains an object of a derived class object

Comment: Agree, dynamic_cast is the only way, and I consider it a feature of last resort

Comment: Nope. Not safely, at least.

Comment: I had imagine something like `auto ptr_B_or_C = dynamic_cast<typeof(ptr_A)>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The thing is: You need to know the type of each variable at compile time. Hence you cannot have a magical function `f` that takes an `A* a` and returns either `B*` or `C*` based on the **runtime information** of the actual type of the object pointed to by `a`. Even for the the following example the function `B::f` will be called but the return type will be of type `A*` since this is determined at compile time.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
struct A {
  virtual A* get_ptr() { std::cout << "A!\n"; return this; }
  virtual ~A() {}
};

struct B: A {
    B* get_ptr() { std::cout << "B!\n"; return this; }
};

void f(A*) { std::cout << "But here A!\n";}

void f(B*) { std::cout << "But here B!\n";}

int main() {
    B b;
    A* a = &b;
    f(a->get_ptr());
}
```

Will print `B!` (since it is virtual) and then call the `A*` (since the compiler assumes that `a->get_ptr()` returns a `A*`) overload.

What you can do is:

- Switch on an enum that you store in the object that corresponds to its type.
- Trial and error with `dynamic_cast`.

Addendum: You will probably not need to cast a pointer to the object you have to the actual type of the object, since you can (as done above) just call the virtual functions and those will call the functions belonging to the actual type of your object. Hence, when you think that you need to do the cast as you described, think again, you probably will not need it.

If you still think you need it, reconsider your design decisions, you are probably doing something very weird.

Comment: nit picking: the type of an *object* does not need to be known at compile time .. that's the whole point of the **dynamic** type of an object. You need to know the type of the variable used to access the object at compile time, though, of course.

Comment: Yes, you are of course right. I find it a bit hard to put that thought into words. I changed a bit and hope that makes it clearer.

Answer (score 1):

It's vaguely unholy, but I've seen:

```
   class B;
   class C;

   class A {
   public :
     virtual B* getAsB() { return nullptr; }
     virtual C* getAsC() { return nullptr; }
   }

   class B : public A {
   public:
     B* getAsB() override { return this; }
   }

   class C : public A {
   public:
     C* getAsC() override { return this; }
   }
```

A more **instruction** cache friendly way to address this is to sort your objects by type, and iterate through all the B's, then all the C's, using code that knows what type it's dealing with.  Yes, instructions get their own cache rows, and flailing all over the place through a large object hierarchy's virtual functions is not a good way to avoid cache misses.  Of course if your call stack gets deep enough it won't matter.

OOD and cache friendliness are often at odds.

Yikes, that got all sermon-ish.  OOD is usually fine, until your performance requirements get dialed up to 11 (I'm lookin at YOU game industry).

Comment: Are you sure this works? I would assume that you need a pair of `virtual`s in `A`. After that it should do exactly the same as `dynamic_cast` if I am not mistaken.

Comment: Derp, too much Java lately.  Fixed.  Also added `override`s.  And yes, it works like dynamic cast, but you can leave RTTI turned off and only add it manually for select classes.  It's overall-cheaper, but creates the potential for bugs.  I haven't seen one of those bugs, but the code bases I've seen this in were pretty mature when I arrived.

Comment: I've also seen instances where there are parallel `const` versions that return `const B*` and `const C*`.  I'd like to see C++23 include the const equivalent of the starship operator.  "This is a whatever-const version of the function that returns a whatever-const type".